# Different types of features to train Naive Bayes in Python Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nltk

I would like to use a number of features to train with Naive Bayes classifier to classify 'A' or 'non-A'.

I have three features of different value types:
1) total_length - in positive integer
2) vowel-ratio - in decimal/fraction
3) twoLetters_lastName - a array containing multiple two-letters strings

```
# coding=utf-8
from nltk.corpus import names
import nltk
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

# Import data into pandas
data = pd.read_csv('XYZ.csv', header=0, encoding='utf-8', 
    low_memory=False)
df = DataFrame(data)

# Randomize records
df = df.reindex(np.random.permutation(df.index))

# Assign column into label Y
df_Y = df[df.AScan.notnull()][['AScan']].values # Labels are 'A' or 'non-A'
#print df_Y

# Assign column vector into attribute X
df_X = df[df.AScan.notnull()][['total_length', 'vowel_ratio', 'twoLetters_lastName']].values
#print df_X[0:10]

# Incorporate X and Y into ML algorithms
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(df_X, df_Y)
```

df_Y is as follow:

```
[[u'non-A']
 [u'A']
 [u'non-A']
 ..., 
 [u'A']
 [u'non-A']
 [u'non-A']]
```

df_X is below:

```
[[9L 0.222222222 u"[u'ke', u'el', u'll', u'ly']"]
 [17L 0.41176470600000004
  u"[u'ma', u'ar', u'rg', u'ga', u'ar', u'ri', u'is']"]
 [11L 0.454545455 u"[u'du', u'ub', u'bu', u'uc']"]
 [11L 0.454545455 u"[u'ma', u'ah', u'he', u'er']"]
 [15L 0.333333333 u"[u'ma', u'ag', u'ge', u'ee']"]
 [13L 0.307692308 u"[u'jo', u'on', u'ne', u'es']"]
 [12L 0.41666666700000005
  u"[u'le', u'ef', u'f\\xe8', u'\\xe8v', u'vr', u're']"]
 [15L 0.26666666699999997 u"[u'ni', u'ib', u'bl', u'le', u'et', u'tt']"]
 [15L 0.333333333 u"[u'ki', u'in', u'ns', u'sa', u'al', u'll', u'la']"]
 [11L 0.363636364 u"[u'mc', u'cn', u'ne', u'ei', u'il']"]]
```

I am getting this error:

```
E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py:150: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:werwer\wer\wer.py", line 32, in <module>
    clf.fit(df_X, df_Y)
  File "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 163, in fit
    self.theta_[i, :] = np.mean(Xi, axis=0)
  File "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2727, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "E:\Program Files Extra\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 69, in _mean
    ret, rcount, out=ret, casting='unsafe', subok=False)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'unicode' and 'long'
```

My understanding is I need to convert the features into one numpy array as a feature vector, but I don't think if I am preparing this X vector right since it contains very different value types.

Comment: Let's start with the error at the top. Before the traceback, the error suggests that you need to reshape your df_Y. Have you tried messing around with that?

Comment: I am not sure what end format it wants. The only thing I can think of is adding a ',' between each row. Is that the problem? I will try coding it tomorrow morning as it is late

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Related questions: [Choosing a Classification Algorithm to Classify Mix of Nominal and Numeric Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14274771/choosing-classification-algorithm-to-classify-mix-of-nominal-and-numeric-data?rq=1) -- [Mixing Categorial and Continuous Data in Naive Bayes Classifier Using Scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254203/mixing-categorial-and-continuous-data-in-naive-bayes-classifier-using-scikit-lea?rq=1)

Okay so there are a few things going on. As DalekSec pointed out, it's best practice to keep all your features as one type as you input them into a model like `GaussianNB`. The traceback indicates that while fitting the model, it tries to divide a string (presumably one of your unicode strings like `u"[u'ke', u'el', u'll', u'ly']"`) by an integer. So what we need to do is convert the training data into a form that sklearn can use. We can do this a few ways, two of which ogrisel eloquently describes in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14255284/4500741).

1. We can convert all the continuous variables to categorical variables. In our case, this means converting `total_length` (in some cases you could probably treat this as a categorical variable, but let's not get ahead of ourselves) and `vowel-ratio`. For instance, you can basically bin the values you see in each feature to one of 5 values based on percentile: 'very small', 'small', 'medium', 'high', 'very high'. There's no real easy way in sk-learn as far as I know, but it should be pretty straightforward to do it yourself. The only thing that you would want to change is that you would want to use `MultinomialNB` instead of `GaussianNB` because you'll be dealing with features that would be better described by multinomial distributions rather than gaussian ones.
2. We can convert the categorical features to numeric ones for use with `GaussianNB`. Personally I find this to be the more intuitive approach. Basically, when dealing with text, you need to figure out what *information* you want to take from the text and pass to the classifier. It looks like to me that you want to extract the incidence of different two letter last names.

   Normally I would ask you whether or not you have all the last names in your dataset, but since each one is only two letters each we can just store all the possible two letter names (including the unicode characters involving accent marks) with a minimal impact on performance. This is where something like sklearn's `CountVectorizer` might be useful. Assuming that you have every possible combination of two letter last names in your data, you can just directly use this to turn a row in your twoLetter_lastname column into a N-dimensional vector that records the number of occurrences of each unique last name in your row. Then just combine this new vector with your other two features into a numpy array.

   In the case you do not have every possible combination of two letters (including accented ones), you should consider generating that list and pass it in as the 'vocabulary' for the CountVectorizer. This is so that your classifier knows how to handle all possible last names. **It's not the end of the world if you don't handle all cases, but any new unseen two letter pairs will be ignored in this scheme.**

   Before you use these tools, you should make sure that you pass your last name column in as a list, and not as a string, as this can result in unintended behavior.

   You can read more about general sklearn preprocessing [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html), and more about `CountVectorizer` and other text feature extraction tools provided by sklearn [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction). I use a lot of these tools daily, and recommend them for basic text extraction tasks. There are also plenty of tutorials and demos available online. You might also look for other types of methods of representation, like binarizing and one-hot encoding. There are many ways to solve this problem, it mostly depends on your specific problem/needs.

---

After you're able to turn all your data into one form or the other, you should be able to make use of either the Gaussian or Multinomial NB classifier. As for your error regarding the 1D vector, you printed df_Y and it looked like

```
[[u'non-A']
 [u'A']
 [u'non-A']
 ..., 
 [u'A']
 [u'non-A']
 [u'non-A']]
```

Basically, it's expecting this to be in a flat list, rather than as a column vector (a list of one-dimensional lists). Just reshape it accordingly by making use of commands like numpy.reshape() or numpy.ravel() (numpy.ravel() would probably be more appropriate, considering that you're dealing with just one column, as the error mentioned).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think scikit-learn.naive_bayes requires a purely numeric feature vector instead of a mixture of text and numbers. It looks like it crashes when trying to "divide" a unicode string by a long integer.

I can't be much help with finding numeric representations for text, but [this scikit-learn tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#extracting-features-from-text-files) might be a good start.

Comment: Thanks I will look into it. Probably doing a bunch of tutorials plus aiming for the ones with features with string is the way to go.